# Safari not prompting for username/password when requested by a CORS url

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, safari

My application is in `PHP` and `AngularJS` (migrating from PHP to AngularJS).

Let us say the `Apache HTTPD` server is on `domain1` and the backend (`Apache Tomcat`) is on `domain2`.

When I request for apps which are in `AngularJS`, the `JavaScript` files are loaded from `domain1`. After the browser has loaded of all `JavaScript` files, `AngularJS` kicks in and the client requests for data from `domain2`.

The `domain2` server wants to authenticate the caller and so responds the browser with a status code `401` and header `WWW-Authenticate: Basic`.

With Chrome, Firefox and IE, the browser prompts for a username and password (**the prompt is the browser in-built one not my custom made**). In Safari it does not, instead in the Safari console I get the following message -

```
http://domain2/request
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status 401 (Unauthorized)
```

The backend server has CORS enabled.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139660/angularjs-basic-example-to-use-authentication-in-single-page-application

Comment: @Vohuman - Thank you, but it does not help me as I want the browser to prompt for the username and password. I do not have a login page.

Comment: Just ran into this same issue. Not sure if it’s a bug or by design, but Safari appears to be the only browser to not honour a Basic WWW-Authenticate challenge on a cross-origin request.