# how to replace url with new url without page refresh in angular js

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I want to refresh a URL upon successful login without a page refresh.
I am using the following code

```
$scope.Login = function (teacher, chkRememberMe) {
    alert(chkRememberMe);
    $http.post("/Teacher/Login", { teacher: teacher, chkRememberMe: chkRememberMe })
    .success(function (result) {
        if (result == "True") {
            toastr.success("You are Login successfully!!!");
            $timeout(function () { }, 5000);
            $timeout(function () { }, 5000);
            $location.path('Teacher/Index');
        }
        else {
            toastr.error("The email and password you entered don't match.")
            window.location = "/Teacher/Login";
        }
    })
    .error(function (error) {
        error.message
        alert(error);
        toastr.error("The email and password you entered don't match11")
    })
}
```

The URL is not updating successfully.

Comment: Fixed wording and spelling errors.

Comment: I believe that what you want is ngRoute which is documented here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Answer (score 0):

You can use `history.replaceState(data,title,url)` to accomplish this. There's a bit of documentation at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API). The [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) library may be of interest as well.

If you're trying to handle single-page authentication with angular, it can be a hassle. You may want to take a look at [AngularJS: Basic example to use authentication in Single Page Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139660/angularjs-basic-example-to-use-authentication-in-single-page-application) for more on this.

An aside: you may also want to consider taking steps to ensure that password managers function as you'd expect. There are a few stackoverflow questions which address these concerns (e.g., [How to make Chrome remember password for an AJAX form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430129/how-to-make-chrome-remember-password-for-an-ajax-form)).

Comment: i am not talking about browser history. i am talking about when any user login first time then we check user name and password if both are correct then move to next page with out url refresh with help of angular js. I am talking about just move from one page to other page without url refresh with help of angular js.